# How to make any method act as __init__ in Python?

Tags: python, methods

When I run something like:

```
class Compliment():
   def __init__(self):
      self.Hello = "HI"
   def Bye(self):
      self.bye = "BYE"
print(Compliment().Hello)
print(Compliment().bye)
```

I get:`

```
AttributeError: 'Compliment' object has no attribute 'bye'
HI
```

But I want to create attributes in others methods, and make the method "init" useless for this purpose, Is this possible? If it is, how could I do something like that?

Comment: ...why? What practical purpose would this serve?

Comment: It is just curiosity

Comment: when you instantiate the class with `Compliment()", the new object in the init will have a variable called Hello. But no variable with the name bye as the function Bye() was never called!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create attributes anywhere you wish.  The error with your code is that you did not invoke method `Bye` before you tried to print an attribute that is created *only* within that method.  Instead, try

```
prop = Compliment()
print(prop.Hello)
prop.Bye()
print(prop.bye)
```

In answer to your direct question: no, you cannot make `__init__` useless for creating attributes.  You do not have to use it that way, but you cannot disable it: `__init__` is a language-defined method.

Comment: I got it, thank you, one more thing: The method __init__ was invoked when I created the object, how can i make the Bye method be called as well, as soon as the object is created such as __init__?

Comment: Anything you want to happen upon creation, you *must* put into `__init__`.  This is part of any tutorial on classes.

Comment: Thank you @Prune, I was thinking the name `__init__` was convetional such as "self" and "cls".

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Compliment():
   def __init__(self):
      self.Hello = "HI"

   @property
   def bye(self):
      return "BYE"
```

```
> print(Compliment().Hello)
HI
> print(Compliment().bye)
BYE
```

python class property decorator is executed at initialization.
It can be automatically generated and used without having to run a separate function.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: "python class property decorator is executed at initialization" - this is extremely misleading and probably wrong as you meant it. Properties are not executed at instance initialization. The `@property` decorator is executed during execution of the class statement, but this does not run the property getter. Property getters are executed each time the property is accessed, which is completely different from what the question is asking for.